# I have a prob with Network plugin in ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using this code to test for connection on my ionic app, but i've got a NULL as i can see.

```
 ionViewDidEnter() {
debugger;
if (this.network.type === 'WIFI') {
  console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
}}
```

Ive got a null in this.network.type as i can see...when i use debugger. Someone know how to resolve this.

Comment: Please Share your .ts file.

Comment: @Najamussaqib http://dpaste.com/0B1FHVQ

Comment: Write this Network Logic in your `app.component.ts`.
don't use it in your pages .ts

Comment: @Najamussaqib   look: http://dpaste.com/119P0BN    it doesnt work again.